# UIPageViewController displays pages out of order and never calls viewControllerBeforeViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have a UIPageViewController and I implemented the two optional methods on the [data source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerDataSourceProtocolRef/UIPageViewControllerDataSource.html) to get the automatic UIPageControl.

I have the following helper methods which convert between indices and view controllers.

```
- (UIViewController *)viewControllerForIndex:(NSInteger)index;
- (NSInteger)indexFromViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

The first method creates a new view controller, configures itself to the specific index, and stores that index in a retrievable location (i.e. one that is accessed by the second method).

I instantiate my page view controller with the following code:

```
[pageViewController setViewControllers:@[[self viewControllerForIndex:0]]
                             direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                              animated:NO
                            completion:nil];
```

And here are my data source methods:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSInteger currentIndex = [self indexFromViewController:viewController];
    if (currentIndex == 0) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return [self viewControllerForIndex:currentIndex-1];
    }
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSInteger currentIndex = [self indexFromViewController:viewController];
    if (currentIndex == self.data.count - 1) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return [self viewControllerForIndex:currentIndex+1];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    return self.data.count;
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    return 0;
}
```

When I navigate forward, everything works properly, when I navigate backwards, view controllers start to appear in random order.

I believe this is related to the fact that pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController: is never called. The page view controller only calls pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:, even when I begin swiping backwards.

The UIPageViewController is configured in a storyboard as follows:

- Navigation: Horizontal
- Transition Style: Scroll
- Spine Location: None
- Double sided: NO

How can I get the page view controller to show view controllers in the proper order?

**Update:** When I copy the code into a brand new project, everything works perfectly. I guess my new question is do you know of any pods, frameworks, linker flags, other settings that might be causing this behavior?

If I present the same page view controller on top of the current page view controller recursively, the bug happens on every odd version of the view controller. (I.e. it happens on the first one, the third one, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was [Taplytics](https://taplytics.com).

I was running version 1.2.34, after updating to 1.2.50, it fixed the problem.